How to get `GenericAlias` super types in python?
Say I have a class defined as follows:
class MyList(list[int]): ...

I'm looking for a method that will return list[int] when I give it MyList, e.g.:
>>> inspect.getsupers(MyList) 
[list[int]]

The trouble is that no such method exists, as far as I can find.  There is inspect.getmro(...), but this only returns list, not list[int].  Is there anything that I can reuse or implement that will give me this, short of some magic involving inspect.getsource(...)?
The context is that I'm trying to write a generic issubtype(t1, t2) method that works for arbitrary classes and GenericAliases.  This is one issue I've run into in writing this method that I'm not sure how to solve.

I'm not sure if that information is kept around anywhere in the class object itself, note, it's not ven in MyList.__bases__

One of the mypy maintainers wrote a library for use cases like this: typing-inspect. You're looking for typing_inspect.get_generic_bases.

Aha! This information is stored in .__orig_bases__. So:
>>> MyList.__orig_bases__
(list[int],)

And on 3.12+, the canonical way would be to use:
>>> import types
>>> types.get_original_bases(MyList)
(list[int],)


Interesting, __orig_bases__ seems to have existed since at least Python 3.8, but doesn't appear to be documented outside the new get_original_bases function.

Thanks! And if you're stuck on python versions older than 3.12, typing_extensions has this method available, though I'm not sure how far back it goes.

@chepner it is mentioned in PEP 560
